# Issue with convergence with SGD with function approximation using polynomial linear regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, convergence, gradient-descent, stochastic-gradient-descent

I was trying to learn a sine curve

$$ f_{target}(x) = sin(2 \pi f_s x )$$

with $f_s = 4$, from 10 points, with linear regression and a polynomial of degree 9:

$$f_{model}(x) = \langle w, \Phi(x) \rangle = \sum^9_{i=0} w_i x^i$$

with Stochastic Gradient Descent/SGD (or GD). I was doing this to play around and get some intuition on early stopping as a regularizer, however, when I tried it the model doesn't seem to train at all (**since the SGD solution error is not close at all to the least squares solution**). I can't figure why but at this point I am more confident it is not a programming issue (because I've implemented SGD with pytorch and tensorflow and both seem to get stuck in the same way).

Therefore, I am assuming I must be doing something else wrong, probably on the statistical/optimization side. I have tried to following to debug the issue:

- choose terms # terms that match the number of data points so that I know there is a unique minimizer (since problem is convex since I am minimizing $ \frac{1}{N_{train}}\| Kw - Y \|^2_{2}$)
- decreased the number of data points to see if there is any point where the loss decreases and it does arrive to order $10^{-6}$ which makes me think nothing is wrong with the code
- tried tensorflow and pytorch and both don't work in the same example.
- computed the unique minimizer with linear algebra tools, so I know for sure empirically (i.e. by computing it) that the minimizer exists and it **does**.
- printed various debugging things as the train, like size of gradients, checking the parameters are being updated, etc
- played around with the batch size, step size $\eta$, # iterations
- visualized solutions, plotted out the solution obtained by SGD vs the one linear algebra solution got and they don't match at all
- tried different initializations (which shouldn't matter since things are convex)
- compared the linear algebra solution vectors vs one obtained via SGD
- I've also briefly tried changing the interval where the learning is doing with much success...

at this point I find it quite mysterious why it wouldn't work if the problem is suppose to be very simple. I should be able to fit the data exactly but I am not able. The problem is convex. So I find it extremely weird.

I will paste the code, it should be completely self contained and run (I omitted the tensorflow code for simplicity, since it already looks more complicated than it should...):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable

def index_batch(X,batch_indices,dtype):
    '''
    returns the batch indexed/sliced batch
    '''
    if len(X.shape) == 1: # i.e. dimension (M,) just a vector
        batch_xs = torch.FloatTensor(X[batch_indices]).type(dtype)
    else:
        batch_xs = torch.FloatTensor(X[batch_indices,:]).type(dtype)
    return batch_xs

def get_batch2(X,Y,M,dtype):
    '''
    get batch for pytorch model
    '''
    # TODO fix and make it nicer, there is pytorch forum question
    X,Y = X.data.numpy(), Y.data.numpy()
    N = len(Y)
    valid_indices = np.array( range(N) )
    batch_indices = np.random.choice(valid_indices,size=M,replace=False)
    batch_xs = index_batch(X,batch_indices,dtype)
    batch_ys = index_batch(Y,batch_indices,dtype)
    return Variable(batch_xs, requires_grad=False), Variable(batch_ys, requires_grad=False)

def get_sequential_lifted_mdl(nb_monomials,D_out, bias=False):
    return torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Linear(nb_monomials,D_out,bias=bias))

def train_SGD(mdl, M,eta,nb_iter,logging_freq ,dtype, X_train,Y_train, X_test,Y_test,c_pinv):
    ##
    N_train,_ = tuple( X_train.size() )
    #print(N_train)
    for i in range(nb_iter):
        for W in mdl.parameters():
            W_before_update = np.copy( W.data.numpy() )
        # Forward pass: compute predicted Y using operations on Variables
        batch_xs, batch_ys = get_batch2(X_train,Y_train,M,dtype) # [M, D], [M, 1]
        ## FORWARD PASS
        y_pred = mdl.forward(batch_xs)
        ## LOSS + Regularization
        batch_loss = (1/M)*(y_pred - batch_ys).pow(2).sum()
        ## BACKARD PASS
        batch_loss.backward() # Use autograd to compute the backward pass. Now w will have gradients
        ## SGD update
        for W in mdl.parameters():
            delta = eta*W.grad.data
            #W.data.copy_(W.data - delta)
            W.data -= delta
        ## train stats
        if i % (nb_iter/50) == 0 or i == 0:
        #if True:
        #if i % logging_freq == 0 or i == 0:
            current_train_loss = (1/N_train)*(mdl.forward(X_train) - Y_train).pow(2).sum().data.numpy()
            print('\n-------------')
            print(f'i = {i}, current_train_loss = {current_train_loss}')
            print(f'N_train = {N_train}')
            print(f'W_before_update={W_before_update}')
            print(f'W.data = {W.data.numpy()}')
            print(f'W.grad.data = {W.grad.data.numpy()}')
            diff = W_before_update - W.data.numpy()
            print(f' w_^(t) - w^(t-1) = {diff/eta}')
            diff_norm = np.linalg.norm(diff, 2)
            print(f'|| w_^(t) - w^(t-1) ||^2 = {diff_norm}')
            print(f'c_pinv = {c_pinv.T}')
            train_error_c_pinv = (1/N_train)*(np.linalg.norm(Y_train.data.numpy() - np.dot(X_train.data.numpy(),c_pinv) )**2)
            print(f'train_error_c_pinv = {train_error_c_pinv}')
        ## Manually zero the gradients after updating weights
        mdl.zero_grad()
##
logging_freq = 100
dtype = torch.FloatTensor
## SGD params
M = 5
eta = 0.03
nb_iter = 100*1000
##
lb,ub=0,1
freq_sin = 4
f_target = lambda x: np.sin(2*np.pi*freq_sin*x).reshape(x.shape[0],1)
N_train = 10
X_train = np.linspace(lb,ub,N_train).reshape(N_train,1)
Y_train = f_target(X_train)
N_test = 200
X_test = np.linspace(lb,ub,N_test).reshape(N_test,1)
Y_test = f_target(X_test)
## degree of mdl
Degree_mdl = 9
## pseudo-inverse solution
c_pinv = np.polyfit( X_train.reshape( (N_train,) ), Y_train , Degree_mdl )[::-1]
## linear mdl to train with SGD
nb_terms = c_pinv.shape[0]
mdl_sgd = get_sequential_lifted_mdl(nb_monomials=nb_terms,D_out=1, bias=False)
#mdl_sgd[0].weight.data.normal_(mean=0,std=0.0)
#mdl_sgd[0].weight.data.fill_(0)
print(f'mdl_sgd[0].weight.data={mdl_sgd[0].weight.data}')
## Make polynomial Kernel
poly_feat = PolynomialFeatures(degree=Degree_mdl)
Kern_train, Kern_test = poly_feat.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(N_train,1)), poly_feat.fit_transform(X_test.reshape(N_test,1))
Kern_train_pt, Y_train_pt = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(Kern_train).type(dtype), requires_grad=False), Variable(torch.FloatTensor(Y_train).type(dtype), requires_grad=False)
Kern_test_pt, Y_test_pt = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(Kern_test).type(dtype), requires_grad=False ), Variable(torch.FloatTensor(Y_test).type(dtype), requires_grad=False)
train_SGD(mdl_sgd, M,eta,nb_iter,logging_freq ,dtype, Kern_train_pt,Y_train_pt, Kern_test_pt,Y_test_pt,c_pinv)
##
legend_mdl = f'SGD solution standard parametrization, number of monomials={nb_terms}, batch-size={M}, iterations={nb_iter}, step size={eta}'
#### PLOTS
X_plot = poly_feat.fit_transform(x_horizontal)
X_plot_pytorch = Variable( torch.FloatTensor(X_plot), requires_grad=False)
##
fig1 = plt.figure()
##
p_sgd_tf, = plt.plot(x_horizontal, Y_tf )
p_sgd_pt, = plt.plot(x_horizontal, [ float(f_val) for f_val in mdl_sgd.forward(X_plot_pytorch).data.numpy() ])
p_pinv, = plt.plot(x_horizontal, np.dot(X_plot,c_pinv))
p_data, = plt.plot(X_train,Y_train,'ro')
## legend
nb_terms = c_pinv.shape[0]
legend_mdl = f'SGD solution standard parametrization, number of monomials={nb_terms}, batch-size={M}, iterations={nb_iter}, step size={eta}'
plt.legend(
        [p_sgd_tf,p_sgd_pt,p_pinv,p_data],
        ['TF '+legend_mdl,'Pytorch '+legend_mdl,f'linear algebra soln, number of monomials={nb_terms}',f'data points = {N_train}']
    )
##
plt.xlabel('x'), plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.show()
```

I am not 100% what is wrong but something that I did find worrying is the values of the coefficients of the linear algebra solution:

```
    c_pinv = [[ -7.36275143e-11   9.94955061e+02  -2.27235773e+04   2.02776690e+05
   -9.45987901e+05   2.56477290e+06  -4.18670905e+06   4.05381875e+06
   -2.14321212e+06   4.76269361e+05]]
```

it makes me feel that the fact that some are really large vs some are really small might be a problem...but I would have expected that SGD with a sufficiently small step size should have worked if ran long enough...but I don't know for sure whats wrong.

Does anyone know how to make it work? Is there something trivially obvious I am doing wrong? This problem seems so simple that its quite puzzling that its not working.

---

Not sure if this is useful but this is some of the stuff that gets printed to my console while debugging:

```
mdl_sgd[0].weight.data=
 0.2769  0.2238 -0.1786 -0.2836  0.0282 -0.2650  0.1517  0.0609 -0.1799  0.2518
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1x10]


-------------
i = 0, current_train_loss = [ 0.51122922]
N_train = 10
W_before_update=[[ 0.276916    0.22384584 -0.17859279 -0.28359878  0.02818507 -0.26502955
   0.15169969  0.06087267 -0.17991513  0.25179213]]
W.data = [[ 0.27278039  0.2223435  -0.17868967 -0.28320512  0.02860935 -0.26476261
   0.15175563  0.06072243 -0.18024531  0.251313  ]]
W.grad.data = [[ 0.13785343  0.05007789  0.00322947 -0.01312203 -0.01414278 -0.00889825
  -0.00186479  0.00500792  0.01100619  0.01597152]]
 w_^(t) - w^(t-1) = [[ 0.13785362  0.05007784  0.00322958 -0.01312196 -0.01414275 -0.00889798
  -0.00186463  0.00500791  0.011006    0.01597106]]
|| w_^(t) - w^(t-1) ||^2 = 0.004487781319767237
c_pinv = [[ -7.36275143e-11   9.94955061e+02  -2.27235773e+04   2.02776690e+05
   -9.45987901e+05   2.56477290e+06  -4.18670905e+06   4.05381875e+06
   -2.14321212e+06   4.76269361e+05]]
train_error_c_pinv = 0.00041026620352414134

-------------
i = 2000, current_train_loss = [ 0.45121056]
N_train = 10
W_before_update=[[ 0.05377455  0.14968246 -0.0918882  -0.18873887  0.0875883  -0.24442779
   0.14100061  0.02913089 -0.22231367  0.20818822]]
W.data = [[ 0.02684817  0.13449876 -0.10165974 -0.19549945  0.08267717 -0.24813652
   0.13810736  0.02681178 -0.22421438  0.20660225]]
W.grad.data = [[ 0.89754611  0.50612354  0.32571793  0.2253527   0.16370434  0.12362462
   0.0964416   0.07730356  0.06335653  0.05286586]]
 w_^(t) - w^(t-1) = [[ 0.89754611  0.50612342  0.32571805  0.22535275  0.16370441  0.1236245
   0.09644181  0.07730357  0.06335676  0.05286584]]
|| w_^(t) - w^(t-1) ||^2 = 0.03397814929485321
c_pinv = [[ -7.36275143e-11   9.94955061e+02  -2.27235773e+04   2.02776690e+05
   -9.45987901e+05   2.56477290e+06  -4.18670905e+06   4.05381875e+06
   -2.14321212e+06   4.76269361e+05]]
train_error_c_pinv = 0.00041026620352414134
```

---

I've done more extensive testing and it seems that for any data set of size 10,30 we can't really approximate the function with gradient descent. Is this what is suppose to be happening?

It seems really odd to me. The main thing I find odd is that based on the intuition from [Nysquit-Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) getting more data points should make the task easier, not harder. I know that the dictionary/basis used for Nysquit is different (i.e. the dictionary is sinusoidals) however, polynomials are not that far away from them specially on a small interval. Or at least thats my intuition. It seems odd that more data points makes the problem harder even though we can just choose the number of features equal to the number of data points and have a totally well defined convex problem.

---

New attempt:

I had time to try the Hermitian polynomial but it didn't change anything as far as I could tell. I changed the step size all over the place but now it either explodes to NaN easierly or it still doesn't train. Not sure what to do anymore...

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from numpy.polynomial.hermite import hermvander

import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable

from maps import NamedDict

from plotting_utils import *

def index_batch(X,batch_indices,dtype):
    '''
    returns the batch indexed/sliced batch
    '''
    if len(X.shape) == 1: # i.e. dimension (M,) just a vector
        batch_xs = torch.FloatTensor(X[batch_indices]).type(dtype)
    else:
        batch_xs = torch.FloatTensor(X[batch_indices,:]).type(dtype)
    return batch_xs

def get_batch2(X,Y,M,dtype):
    '''
    get batch for pytorch model
    '''
    # TODO fix and make it nicer, there is pytorch forum question
    X,Y = X.data.numpy(), Y.data.numpy()
    N = len(Y)
    valid_indices = np.array( range(N) )
    batch_indices = np.random.choice(valid_indices,size=M,replace=False)
    batch_xs = index_batch(X,batch_indices,dtype)
    batch_ys = index_batch(Y,batch_indices,dtype)
    return Variable(batch_xs, requires_grad=False), Variable(batch_ys, requires_grad=False)

def get_sequential_lifted_mdl(nb_monomials,D_out, bias=False):
    return torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Linear(nb_monomials,D_out,bias=bias))

def train_SGD(mdl, M,eta,nb_iter,logging_freq ,dtype, X_train,Y_train):
    ##
    N_train,_ = tuple( X_train.size() )
    #print(N_train)
    for i in range(nb_iter):
        # Forward pass: compute predicted Y using operations on Variables
        batch_xs, batch_ys = get_batch2(X_train,Y_train,M,dtype) # [M, D], [M, 1]
        ## FORWARD PASS
        y_pred = mdl.forward(batch_xs)
        ## LOSS + Regularization
        batch_loss = (1/M)*(y_pred - batch_ys).pow(2).sum()
        ## BACKARD PASS
        batch_loss.backward() # Use autograd to compute the backward pass. Now w will have gradients
        ## SGD update
        for W in mdl.parameters():
            delta = eta*W.grad.data
            W.data.copy_(W.data - delta)
        ## train stats
        if i % (nb_iter/10) == 0 or i == 0:
            current_train_loss = (1/N_train)*(mdl.forward(X_train) - Y_train).pow(2).sum().data.numpy()
            print('\n-------------')
            print(f'i = {i}, current_train_loss = {current_train_loss}\n')
            print(f'eta*W.grad.data = {eta*W.grad.data}')
            print(f'W.grad.data = {W.grad.data}')
        ## Manually zero the gradients after updating weights
        mdl.zero_grad()
##
logging_freq = 100
dtype = torch.FloatTensor
## SGD params
M = 3
eta = 0.002
nb_iter = 20*1000
##
lb,ub = 0,1
f_target = lambda x: np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
N_train = 5
X_train = np.linspace(lb,ub,N_train)
Y_train = f_target(X_train)
## degree of mdl
Degree_mdl = 4
## pseudo-inverse solution
c_pinv = np.polyfit( X_train, Y_train , Degree_mdl )[::-1]
## linear mdl to train with SGD
nb_terms = c_pinv.shape[0]
mdl_sgd = get_sequential_lifted_mdl(nb_monomials=nb_terms,D_out=1, bias=False)
mdl_sgd[0].weight.data.normal_(mean=0,std=0.001)
## Make polynomial Kernel
#poly_feat = PolynomialFeatures(degree=Degree_mdl)
#Kern_train = poly_feat.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(N_train,1))
Kern_train = hermvander(X_train,Degree_mdl)
Kern_train = Kern_train.reshape(N_train,Kern_train.shape[1])
Kern_train_pt, Y_train_pt = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(Kern_train).type(dtype), requires_grad=False), Variable(torch.FloatTensor(Y_train).type(dtype), requires_grad=False)
train_SGD(mdl_sgd, M,eta,nb_iter,logging_freq ,dtype, Kern_train_pt,Y_train_pt)

#### PLOTTING
x_horizontal = np.linspace(lb,ub,1000).reshape(1000,1)
#X_plot = poly_feat.fit_transform(x_horizontal)
X_plot = hermvander(x_horizontal,Degree_mdl)
X_plot = X_plot.reshape(1000,X_plot.shape[2])
X_plot_pytorch = Variable( torch.FloatTensor(X_plot), requires_grad=False)
##
fig1 = plt.figure()
#plots objs
p_sgd, = plt.plot(x_horizontal, [ float(f_val) for f_val in mdl_sgd.forward(X_plot_pytorch).data.numpy() ])
p_pinv, = plt.plot(x_horizontal, np.dot(X_plot,c_pinv))
p_data, = plt.plot(X_train,Y_train,'ro')
## legend
nb_terms = c_pinv.shape[0]
legend_mdl = f'SGD solution standard parametrization, number of monomials={nb_terms}, batch-size={M}, iterations={nb_iter}, step size={eta}'
plt.legend(
        [p_sgd,p_pinv,p_data],
        [legend_mdl,f'linear algebra soln, number of monomials={nb_terms}',f'data points = {N_train}']
    )
##
plt.xlabel('x'), plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.show()
```

---

The main issue seems that I can't get the SGD solution to match the linear algebra error (via inverse or pseudo-inverse) with either parametrization of the data matrix $X$ (standard polynomials or Hermite polynomials).

e.g.

With Hermite:

```
-----------------
train_error_pinv = 6.006056840733974e-09
final_sgd_error = [ nan]
```

With standard:

```
-----------------
train_error_pinv = 5.205485509746132e-20
final_sgd_error = [ 4.50123644]
```

Comment: The problem goes away if you use a Hermite polynomial basis, which has theoretically the same solution for $\widehat Y$. This suggests that the problem is because your predictors are highly-colinear. Additionally, the predictors are at vastly different scales.

Comment: @guy why does the problem only occur if I use my given basis when I do SGD learning but not when use linear algebra solvers? LikeI don't understand how the basis matters or how the basis only affect one type of learning algorithm and not another.

Comment: I would guess that, if you use a bad basis, then the geometry of the loss function is messy in a way that the usual linear algebra solvers are invariant to. Solving the normal equations exactly makes use of second order information in the hessian. It seems like the difficulty for SGD is probably determined by the ratio of the largest and smallest eigenvalues of the Hessian, hence using an orthogonal basis is the best-cast scenario, while using a basis like $\psi_j(x) = x^j$ is a disaster because $x^j$ and $x^{j+1}$ are highly correlated. But I don't know, I'm just guessing.

Comment: @guy why are $x^j$ and $x^{j+1}$ correlated? I understand what it means for vectors to be independent and measure it in the context of linear algebra, but what does it mean for two monomials to be correlated and how do I measure the degree to which they are related or independent?

Comment: @guy thanks for your guess, it will give me some stuff to think about (try things out). For the moment, lets assume that I do want be stubborn and stick with the parametrization of the model that I have. Is it possible to simply choose a different target function in some way so to avoid this issue (without having to change the actual model)? Or even better choose a number of training exampled (or number of parameters) such that SGD problem behaves well?

Comment: Two functions $f, g$ are highly correlated if they are nearly parallel in some underlying vector space. The most natural vector space of functions for your setting is $L_2([0,1])$, the set of functions with $\int_0^1 f(x)^2 \, dx < \infty$, with inner product $\langle f, g\rangle = \int_0^1 f(x) \cdot g(x) \, dx$. Then the correlation is $\langle f_0, g_0\rangle / \|f_0\| \|g_0\|$ where $f_0 = f - \int f, g_0 = g - \int g$.

Comment: I would try just doing fisher scoring and see if you can get that to work, then if it does see if you can just get vanilla gradient descent to work. If those don't work, then SGD won't work either, obviously.

Comment: Another problem, that I should have noticed earlier, is that the 9th degree polynomial cannot do a good job of approximating your function, in the sense that its projection onto the subspace of 9th degree polynomials is far away from the truth. Hermite polynomials fix the problem if you also also set $f_s = 1$. Otherwise, you need to up the degree.

Comment: @guy I don't think I understand your argument about the projection of 9th degree polynomials. Like, the target function is a sin thus it would seem to need an infinite degree polynomial. Or did you mean that the monomial of degree 9 does an extra bad job compared to all the other monomials I am using?

Comment: You need to go beyond 9th degree. The function oscillates too much to be picked up by a 9th degree polynomial, there are already 8 local optima when $f_s = 4$ on $[0,1]$. This is if you are trying to actually recover the true function, a 9th degree will still interpolate 10 points just fine.

Comment: @guy thanks for your help and patience so far guy. But I really wanted to try the current parametrization of the model for the time being (I guess I'd avoid fisher scores for the moment and hermite poly's for the moment). Do you think there is a way to make the loss function landscape more stable by choosing a different target function or sampling the input space differently isntead of evenly spaced?

Comment: @guy so sad guy, I tried hermitian polynomial! No luck :( The problem didn't seem to have changed at all...odd right?

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, I replicated your simulation settings in `R` and it worked for me. Everything I mentioned in my comments was after trying things out myself.

Comment: @guy by worked fine what do u mean? Do you mean that you managed the train error to decrease close to zero? Cuz my error usually gets stuck and the function learned looks nothing like the target function...I assume u mean u managed to approximate the function just fine?

Comment: I interpolated the 10 fixed values. If the goal is to reproduce the true function, and you add more data points, then (as I mentioned above) you need to use more than a 9th degree polynomial because a 9th degree polynomial is not flexible enough to estimate the true function. But I also succeeded at that, after bumping the degree up to 20.

Comment: @guy the goal is not to reproduce the true function. The goal is to have GD (or SGD) train at all. It seems to me that something happens during training but the loss doesn't go down. I would have expected that the loss eventually gets really close to whatever linear algebra methods (pseudo-inverse or inverses) get. So my surprise is that GD does not seem to update the model in any meaningful way (not even memorize the training set even though there it should be with enough parameters). Thats why I was curious what you meant that it worked in R for you.

Comment: Then you must be doing something wrong, because when I used hermite polynomials I got SGD to reproduce the linear algebra solution.

Comment: @guy did you try the "standard/normal" parametrization instead of the hermite. I am really curious to know if that worked in R.

Comment: Yes, I did, and no, it did not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69088/discussion-between-charlie-parker-and-guy).

Comment: I would check out the Hessian of your data matrix. Your true values imply that the dimensions are on completely different scales which is going to give SGD a very difficult time. SGD is going to converge at speeds proportional to the condition number of the inverse of your Hessian so if it is as ill-conditioned as it looks based on the linear algebra solutions it will seem as though it is not converging even if you run it for 10^6+ iterations. Since your problem is small, including second order information should not be a problem and ought to converge quite quickly.

Comment: @guy actually I just realized one initial bug with the code which I fixed and now it trains for some data sets (but not all of them). The issues is with pytorch. Its detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47165079/how-to-train-a-simple-linear-regression-model-with-sgd-in-pytorch-successfully/47188974#47188974

however I am still having issues training it with other data sets. Like a train size of size 14 is problematic from a sine curve with frequency 4.

Answer (score 4):

Just so you can move beyond your doubts about my comments on the OP, here is the code I originally used which led to my comments. This should show definitively that, yes, it works with Hermite polynomials and therefore the problem has to do with the design matrix. This is stochastic gradient descent with a batch size of 2, compared with the least squares fit. You can also check for yourself that if you comment the Hermite basis and uncomment the basis you are using that SGD no longer works.

```
set.seed(1234)

N <- 10
x <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, length = N)
mu <- sin(2 * pi * x * 4)
y <- mu
plot(x,y)

X <- cbind(1, poly(x = x, degree = 9))
# X <- sapply(0:9, function(i) x^i)
w <- rnorm(10)

learning_rate <- function(t) .1 / t^(.6)

n_samp <- 2
for(t in 1:100000) {
  mu_hat <- X %*% w
  idx <- sample(1:N, n_samp)
  X_batch <- X[idx,]
  y_batch <- y[idx]
  score_vec <- t(X_batch) %*% (y_batch - X_batch %*% w)

  change <- score_vec * learning_rate(t)
  w <- w + change
}

plot(mu_hat, ylim = c(-1, 1))
lines(mu)
fit_exact <- predict(lm(y ~ X - 1))
lines(fit_exact, col = 'red')
abs(w - coef(lm(y ~ X - 1)))
```

If you want to apply this fix in general, you can replace your design matrix with the Q matrix from the QR, but this is probably not realistic for problems large enough that you would want to use SGD in the first place.

Hopefully that is helpful, but I'm not going to debug your code.

Comment: what I don't understand still is what the relation between condition numbers/orthogonality has on the loss function/energy landscape. Like its more clear that linear algebra solvers would have issues with bad condition numbers but I don't understand mathematically what issue the iterative method Gradient Descent has....

Comment: Look at the form of gradient descent. It moves in the direction of the gradient without regard to the curvature. If one dimension has a near zero gradient for a great distance and all the others are not near zero with unit curvature you will make no progress along the one dimension.

Comment: my comment might be to deep on the question comments but I did find the source of a bug, essentially there is an mistake on how the loss is computed. Details can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47165079/how-to-train-a-simple-linear-regression-model-with-sgd-in-pytorch-successfully/47188974#47188974

Comment: sorry I'm not familiar with R, what is `
learning_rate <- function(t) .1 / t^(.6)` doing?

Comment: on your final comment you mean solve $ \ | Qw - Y \|^2$ instead of $\| Xw - Y \|$, right? Is it obvious that they should have an equivalent minimum in some exact sense or why can we just go ahead and do that?

Comment: (1) if you want to converge to the global minimum, a requirement for stochastic gradient descent is that the learning rate $\gamma_t$ satisfies $\sum_t \gamma_t = \infty$ and $\sum_t \gamma_t^2 < \infty$. So that is what I did, where `learning_rate(t)` returns $\gamma_t \propto t^{-0.6}$. (2) About why you can use the $Q$ instead of $X$, they have the same column space so they will produce the same fitted $\widehat Y$ (not the same $w$, but you can also get that easily). If that's not clear, I think it would be worth your time to pick up some more linear algebra.

Comment: I think I found the error. My hermite polynomial feature data matrix does not seem to match yours (I am just using python built in)...anyway, do you mind explaining what: 

    `X <- cbind(1, poly(x = x, degree = 9))` 

does?

Comment: actually if you know which orthogonal polynomials it uses it would be super helpful! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47628131/what-type-of-orthogonal-polynomials-does-r-use

Comment: another question, if we were trying to solve a similar problem but now with logistic regression, is it likely that its hessian would also be extremely large due to the polynomial basis?

Answer (score 2):

I would check out the Hessian of your data matrix. Your true values imply that the dimensions are on completely different scales which is going to give SGD a very difficult time. SGD is going to converge at speeds proportional to the condition number of the inverse of your Hessian [Intuitively this implies that it does not account for curvature so dimensions for which the gradient is already near zero relative to the other dimensions will change very slowly]. If it is as ill-conditioned as it looks based on the linear algebra solutions it will seem as though it is not converging even if you run it for 10^10+ iterations.

Since your data matrix is very small, including second order information will not be a problem. Using Newton's Method (you don't need to use a stochastic method, and in fact ***should not*** use one for this problem), you will be scaling your search direction by the inverse of the Hessian which will solve the conditioning problem.

Comment: why does my problem have such different scale problems? I am just sampling from a sine curve...why is that sooo problematic?

Comment: I can't say for sure but likely because you have a 9 degree polynomial. If $ x=.1$ then $x^9=.1^9$, a problem that is exacerbated as you get nearer to zero or much greater than 1.

Comment: how can you tell it has a bad condition number just by looking at the entries of the linear algebra solution?

Comment: Do u predict that changing to hermite polynomials should fix the issue that SGD/GD is giving?

Comment: The scaling of the solution, and the fact that sgd does not work while the linear algebra solution does suggests that it might be the case, but you'd have to check for sure. Recall that the linear algebra solution is $\hat{w} = (A^TA)^{-1}A^TY. $The Hessian is $A^TA.$

Comment: And yes, orthogonal polynomials ought to solve the problem as well. Implementing Newton's method would probably be easier though, depending on what you're more comfortable with

Comment: Sorry if this is a noob question but when I have X^TX what do i do with it? What am I looking for?

Comment: The condition number is the largest over the smallest singular value. If that is very much larger than 1 (say, 100+) then your problem could benefit from one of the fixes suggested.

Comment: The fix that Im most interested in is the data one right now...so is it possible to change the hessian thus the condition number when if we change where we sample? I also noticed that a freq of 1 and 5 data points worked like charm but the more complex and more data caused problems...

Comment: sorry if this is another noob question, but what does it mean wrt to my energy landscape to have large condition numbers for the hessian?

Comment: Sorry for so many question, however, you've been amazingly helpful! :D I was wondering, is there a way to estimate given a step-size how many iterations we need given the condition number? I guess I am curious how you know that once we have 100+ condition number on the hessian we might need lots of iterations.

Comment: That was really just me throwing a number out there. The issue of convergence rate is very challenging. It is dealt with in this paper: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/bottou-lecun-2004a.pdf where they show that the constant in the linear convergence of SGD depends on the condition number. Roughly, we might expect that if $CN= \alpha$ then it will take $\alpha$ times as many iterations for SGD to converge compared to $CN=1$. This is a gross oversimplification but is a fair estimate. In general, once the CN gets large it is time to begin thinking of ways to make the problem better posed.

Comment: not sure if this another noob question David, but is there a way to see that obviously the standard parametrization of the data matrix would result in bad condition numbers? Like what about it was ought to bring problems?

Comment: another question, if we were trying to solve a similar problem but now with logistic regression, is it likely that its hessian would also be extremely large due to the polynomial basis?